# Trying to set the value of a Void* for a custom array, ONLY works if void* set from std::cin

Tags: c++

```
void* val = 0;
cout << "\n\tSelect a value to enter: "; cin >> val;        
SDI::StoredData* temp = new SDI::StoredData();
temp->data = val;       
ARR->insert(temp,0,false);
```

^this, works. value is stored, my `getAllValues` function works perfectly.

doing the EXACT same thing like so:

```
void* val = new int(10);
SDI::StoredData* temp = new SDI::StoredData();
temp->data = val;       
ARR->insert(temp,0,false);
```

or

```
int val = 10;
void* val = &val;
SDI::StoredData* temp = new SDI::StoredData();
temp->data = val;       
ARR->insert(temp,0,false);
```

or any other variation returns a null value, why on EARTH is this happening? and yes, I know, I shouldn't be using `void*` but it's a requirement. Thanks!

edit:

```
for(int i = 0; i<max; i++)
{       
    if(data[i].data!= nullptr)
    {


     int *p = (int*)data[i].data;


     }
}
```

Comment: The last example won't work if `*temp` is intended to survive past the scope this code lives in, since the local won't exist later.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem!

Comment: `cin` is setting the value of the pointer (i.e. where it is pointing to), not the data at which the pointer is pointing. I suspect you are not returning the actual value at the memory location of the pointer (i.e. example 2 looks good at a glance), but are instead returning the value of the pointer (i.e. the memory location it points to).

Comment: chao: why does it work in the first example? and dietmar: the value on 'getAllValues' is returned as null, @RageD it seems to be returning random values http://puu.sh/6jbMB.png the two numbers we're originally DIFFERENT values, and can be seen entering the 'insert' method as such

Comment: @xBroak: could you post how you are retrieving values?

Comment: @RageD added to post, but like i said, works fine when using cin?

Comment: @xBroak: And the return statement? Sorry, are you returning `p` or `*p`? Or how are you using `p` to check its value?

Comment: i am returning *p sorry @RageD

Comment: what does the SDI (whatever that is) documentation say?

Comment: SDI is just my own name space: http://puu.sh/6jceQ.png @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @xBroak: In regards to your `std::cin` example: you're setting the pointer value of `val` to memory location of the value of `std::cin`. That is, if you input `10`, you are effectively setting `val = 10` rather than `val = new int(10);`. This is why it seems as though you are forgetting to dereference somewhere. Likewise, for examples using memory addresses, this is why it would seem you are getting "random values." They are likely not random, but virtual memory addresses.

Comment: please post a **complete but minimal** example that "works". also post a **complete but minimal** example that exhibits the problematic behavior. describe what you expected and how the actual result differs.

Comment: -1 **NOT REAL CODE**. The `int val = 10; void* val = &val;` is invalid code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf that's what happens when i type an example on the browser

Comment: just don't. instead paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine the code that "works".

```
void* val = 0;
cout << "\n\tSelect a value to enter: "; cin >> val;
```

You're calling `cin.operator>>(void*)`, which work pretty much like the getters for numeric types -- it reads a number, and stores it in `val`.

So here, `temp->data` is not a pointer to anything; it is the actual number entered.

As for your second snippet:

```
void* val = new int(10);
```

In this case, `val` isn't a number.  It's the *address* of a number.  (Yes, an address is technically a number as well.  Which is the only reason your first snippet works at all.  But here, it's not 10; it's something like `0x30528680`, the address of an object that *contains* the number 10.)

And as for your third:

```
int val = 10;
void* val = &val;
```

If this were even to compile, `val` would be a pointer to a local variable, which will only exist til the end of the function it's in.  The instant you return, the value would point to who-knows-what.  (Course, it won't compile, cause you're trying to redefine `val`...)

Comment: OK, all makes sense, how might i cast an int 'number' to a void then without a CIN? as appose to the address? or should i dereference somewhere

Comment: OK! using void* val = (void*)intval; seems to have done the job

Comment: Yeah...`void* val = (void*) some_int;` will work.  But for reference, it's freaking hideous.  :P  Pointers that aren't really pointers tend to give me the willies.